# Can't read value from '.env' file in my hardhat project

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, dotenv

I am trying to read variable values from my `.env` file here, but all I am getting is values are undefined.

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require('dotenv').config()

const RINKEBY_RPC_URL = process.env.RINKEBY_RPC_URL
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: RINKEBY_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 4,
    }
  },
  solidity: "0.8.8",
};
```

Error:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.rinkeby.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: rinkeby - Expected string, received undefined
  
To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
```

I have filled my `.env` file like this:

```
RINKEBY_RPC_URL=dummyUrl.com    
PRIVATE_KEY=13133private90994
```

I have tested my code by directly putting RPC URL and private key in my config file and it is working successfully, conforming it is an env file issue.

BTW, I'm using a Macbook pro with the new M1 Pro, maybe OS is causing this issue?

any thoughts on why this issue is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

Import and call `config()` from `"dotenv"` on the first line in `hardhat.config.js`

i.e.:

```js
// import config before anything else
import { config as dotEnvConfig } from "dotenv";
dotEnvConfig();
```

Explanation:

1. I like to import `config` as `dotEnvConfig` because `config` might be used by another library.
2. The function `config` takes an optional `options` object as parameter

```js
options?: {
  path?: string; // default: `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')`
  encoding?: string; // default: `utf8`
  debug?: boolean; // default: `false`
  override?: boolean; // default: `false`
}
```

Usually, `.env` file should be in the root next to your `hardhat.config.js` file. If not, you can define your custom path.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your env file is in the same directory *hardhat.config.js* is, you can try this:

`require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })`.

Comment: `path` is an optional parameter, and it's already defaulted to `path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')` so there's no need to define if it's returning the same value

Answer (score 0):

Just import dotenv/config in hardhat.config file:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "dotenv/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
```